# How to do something based on user input?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator, and I want the user to choose an operation at the start. I can run it fine, but it won't call the add method. Here is my code:

```
     operation = input("Choose an operation: ")

def Addition():
    print("Hello, world")

def ChooseOperation():
    if (operation == "Addition"):
        Addition()
```

Comment: you need to call `ChooseOperation`. (Or, better yet, take the `ChooseOperation` code out of a function.)

Comment: Where do you call `ChooseOperation` (should be `choose_operation` per PEP-8)?

Comment: defs are normally not capitalized... thats what jonrsharpe tries to explain with PEP-8 coding convention rule.Besides that... make it a minimal example that can be run by anyone. (hints towards: `if __name__ == main():  <your code>`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't run the function `ChooseOperation`. Since you probably want to pass operation as an argument, the code should be:

```
def Addition():
    print("Hello, world")

def ChooseOperation(operation):
    if (operation == "Addition"):
        Addition()

operation = input("Choose an operation: ")
ChooseOperation(operation)
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I restart the program in the addition method for a different operation?

Comment: You can put a while-loop around the 2 last lines, and when the user types 'stop' quit the loop or something alike.